# Can't get $.getScript to work

Tags: jquery, getscript

I'm trying to load a custom javascript for cloudzoom on desktops and a other one for touch devices.

In my  i have this piece of code:

```
        if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement){
            // It's a touch screen device.
           $.getScript('/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js'), 
               $(function() {
                  alert('iPad Load was performed.');
                });
        }
        else {
            $.getScript('/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.custom.js'), 
            $(function() {
              alert('Custom Load was performed.');
            });
        }
```

This works fine. But when i remove the alert the script will not load... I don't get a error in the console of firefox either. How can i make it work without alerting something.

Comment: Are you removing only the alert? Or the entire callback section?

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error.

You wrote

```
$.getScript(...),
$(function() { });
```

The `,` is invalid and should not be there.

If you want to pass a script callback, write

```
$.getScript("...", function() { ... });
```

Comment: The problem is that this:

`else {
 $.getScript('/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.custom.js'); 
}`

is not working. And the script does get loaded when i use the above code. When i try: 

`$.getScript('/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.custom.js', function() {
      alert('Custom Load was performed.');
    });`


i dont get anything at all. No error no alert en no functioning cloudzoom.

Comment: What do you see in the Net tab? What happens if you set Break on all Exceptions?

Comment: /js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.custom.js?_=1336138844596 4ms. What do you mean with break?

Comment: Do you see a response for that? Do you see it in the Scripts tab?

Comment: There is a Break on all Exceptions button in the upper right corner of the Console tab.

Comment: It is in the XHR tab. Not in de Scripts tab. Don't know why